# How to push just the content of a eclipse project into github

Tags: eclipse, github, project

a few Youtube videos are showing how to connect eclipse with github and push the Project folder into a github repository. But I do not want shown the project folder as first in my github repository. There should be the **content** of that project folder from eclipse, like others have.

So how can I do that?

Comment: Manually add the other directories and files to the commit, instead of committing the entire project folder. See the [git add documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

Comment: If you right-click a not yet shared project and choose _Team > Share Project..._ you can set the _Path within repository_.